# Return most recent non blank cell value in a given month and year

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, match

I'd like to find the most recent non-blank entry in the following table for the month of December in 2017:

[image]

In this example, the returned value would be 3, the entry under the date header 18-Dec-17, since 25-Dec-17 is blank/non-numerical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `LOOKUP` to do this, e.g.

`=LOOKUP(2,1/(TEXT(A1:Z1,"mmm-yy")="Dec-17")/(A2:Z2<>""),A2:Z2)`

Comment: This works well, but I don't understand the syntax and why a lookup value of 2 returns the correct result. If you could explain, I would greatly appreciate it.  To help with this, I have modified your equation to only include columns A:F and I have evaluated each argument: =LOOKUP(2,{#DIV/0!,1,1,1,#DIV/0!,#DIV/0!},{2,1,2,3,0,5})

Comment: As you can see the first array only returns either 1, when conditions are met, or an error. When lookup value is a number greater than any number in that array (as it will always be here with lookup value 2) then that matches with the last number in the first array ( the third 1) and the correspondingly positioned number is returned from the second array. I’ll add some explanation to my answer

Answer (score 2):

Try,

```
=INDEX(2:2, AGGREGATE(14, 6, COLUMN(A:F)/((MONTH(A1:F1)=12)*(YEAR(A1:F1)=2017)*SIGN(LEN(A2:F2))), 1))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Jeeped.  Works well.  Is there any advantage to this approach as compared to the shorter approach from @barry houdini?

Comment: There are inevitably several ways to accomplish the same thing in excel and everyone has their favorite methods and functions. The text conversion and comparison may be marginally slower than integer multiplication and error control but I would have to run speed tests to find out.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
=+INDEX(A2:F2,1,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(A2:F2),0,0),0)-1)
```

That will return 3 in your case. Just update the 'A2:F2' part if you have a longer array.